# Compare files stored on svn with files on local drive

Tags: powershell, svn

I am trying to write a script on PowerShell that will compare svn files with local files and then to display the files that have changes. I would like also to display files name that exist on local drive but not on svn location.

My code is:

```
$list1 = (svn list C:\Users\name\Desktop\Workingfiles\)

foreach ($thisFile in $list1){
    Write-Host $thisFile
    $var = (svn diff C:\Users\name\Desktop\Workingfiles\$thisFile svn://server/files/Users/name/$thisFile )
    # Write-Host $var
}
```

Comment: `svn diff` is for comparing different revisions of a file in the repository, not for comparing a file in the repository to a file outside the repository. Use the regular file comparison utilities of your system for the latter (`diff`, `fc`, `Compare-Object`, ...).

Comment: I thought that it was possible because at linux you can do it I think with the grep index command

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`svn diff`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html) command with [`--old`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.old) and [`--new`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.new) options. However, it seems that you can not diff repository item with a local unversioned one. You should be able to diff a file from working copy with unversioned file, though.

But what about writing repo file's content into a file? Here is an example:

```
svn cat URL-TO-FILE > file-from-repo.txt
svn diff --old file-from-repo.txt --new local-file.txt
```